# Trying to install tkinter library on a chromebook but get a 404 page error

Tags: python, pip

Im trying to install tkinter for python3

```
pip3 install tkinter
```

I am getting this error

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 404 Client
Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/tkinter/
```

Is the website not working or something?

Comment: try:   `pip install tkinter` without the 3.

Comment: @D.L: you can't install tkinter with pip

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Comment: It says it is already installed. How would I use this then?